# RELAX NG Compact Syntax regular expression support?

Tags: xml, regex, relaxng

Is it possible to define a pattern for `text` in RELAX NG Compact Syntax in the way Regular Expressions are defined, or, maybe even simpler variations of regular grammar which only has "or" and character classes / sequencing operations?

Essentially, I would like to declare an attribute as only allowing values that would otherwise match this regexp: `0x[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}`. I could limit it to `minLength` and `maxLength`, but I'm not sure if I can define a rule for the characters.

Comment: Theoretically, regular languages **only** contain alternation and repetition.

Comment: ah right. I somehow misread "simpler variations" for "simpler subsets" or something like that. Nevermind then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/relax-CHP-9.html describes regular expression support in RELAX NG.

An example, in the compact syntax, can be found in https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/blob/master/csl.rnc :

```
element cs:issn { issn }
issn = xsd:string { pattern = "\d{4}\-\d{3}(\d|x|X)" }
```